# java.lang.StackOverflowError exception on nested objects primitive values in Java Object Serialization

Tags: serialization, data-structures, java-8, range-tree

I have `RangeTreeIndex` and `RangeTreeNode` class which I'm using to build the index and after inserting 2500 records, after that, I'm trying to save `RangeTreeIndex` object in the file where I'm receiving `StackOverflowError`, below is my entire code:

```
public class RangeTreeNode<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;

    public T key;
    public Object data;
    public RangeTreeNode<T> left;
    public RangeTreeNode<T> right;

    public RangeTreeNode() {
    }
}

public class RangeTreeIndex implements Serializable {

    private RangeTreeNode<Number> root;
    private RangeTreeNode<Number> firstLeafNode;
    private RangeTreeNode<Number> lastLeafNode;
    private Number min;
    private Number max;

    public RangeTreeIndex() {
    }

    @Override
    public int insert(Number key, Object values) {
        Number newKey = new Double(key.doubleValue());

        if (newKey.doubleValue() < min.doubleValue()) {
            min = new Double(key.doubleValue());
        }
        if (newKey.doubleValue() > max.doubleValue()) {
            max = new Double(key.doubleValue());
        }

        RangeTreeNode<Number> newNode = new RangeTreeNode<>(newKey, values);
        this.root = this.insert(root, newNode);

        if (firstLeafNode == null && lastLeafNode == null) {
            firstLeafNode = newNode;
            lastLeafNode = newNode;
        } else if (newNode.key.doubleValue() < firstLeafNode.key.doubleValue()) {
            firstLeafNode = newNode;
        } else if (newNode.key.doubleValue() > lastLeafNode.key.doubleValue()) {
            lastLeafNode = newNode;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    private RangeTreeNode<Number> insert(RangeTreeNode<Number> parentNode, RangeTreeNode<Number> newNode) {
        if (parentNode == null) {
            parentNode = newNode;
        } else {
            if (newNode.key.doubleValue() <= parentNode.key.doubleValue()) {
                parentNode.left = insert(parentNode.left, newNode);
            } else {
                parentNode.right = insert(parentNode.right, newNode);
            }
        }

        return parentNode;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "XYZ.jobject";
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
             FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(raf.getFD());
             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);
             ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
            oOut.writeObject(preferenceIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the exception I'm receiving:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.java:836)
    at java.io.Bits.putDouble(Bits.java:121)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.getPrimFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2168)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrimFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1389)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Even if I'm using `Apache commons-lang` library class `SerializationUtils.serialize` with passing only a serializable object it throws the same error.

Can anyone faced this problem like that with primitive values?

Comment: The primitive values is a red herring. When the stack is exhausted, *any* subsequent method invocation may hit the end, without being responsible itself. The problem is not the deepmost method invocation processing a `double`, the problem are the thousands method invocations already on the stack. Unfortunately, serialization is known for high stack consumption. One thing to check, is whether the tree is *balanced*. Unbalanced trees may cause performance problems at other place too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the tree is not balanced, but I think I have found one glitch is that I should create a list to store the data of the same key, rather than placing again into the left node.